# How I can put a figure in bottom right at beamer?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I want to put a this figure in bottom right at beamer and doesn't move.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table, x11names]{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[black, fill=gray!50] (-0.2,2) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,2) -- (2,2); % segmento
                \draw[black, fill=brown!50] (2.2,2) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw[black, fill=gray!50] (-0.2,1) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,2) -- (2,1); % segmento
                \draw[black, fill=brown!50] (2.2,1) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw[black, fill=gray!50] (-0.2,0) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,2) -- (2,0); % segmento
                \draw[black, fill=brown!50] (2.2,0) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,1) -- (2,2); % segmento
                %\draw[black, fill=gray!50] (4.2,2) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,1) -- (2,1); % segmento
                %\draw[black, fill=gray!50] (4.2,1.5) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,1) -- (2,0); % segmento
                %\draw[black, fill=gray!50] (4.2,1) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,0) -- (2,2); % segmento
                %\draw[black, fill=gray!50] (4.2,2) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,0) -- (2,1); % segmento
                %\draw[black, fill=gray!50] (4.2,1.5) circle [radius=0.2];
                \draw (0,0) -- (2,0); % segmento
                %\draw[black, fill=gray!50] (4.2,1) circle [radius=0.2];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `beamer` contents should be in frames ...

Comment: Do you want to have the this picture on a single slide, or on all slides of your presentation?

Comment: I want in a single in both ways because I need it in different documents